# Form Emailing in HTML and PHP not working

Tags: php, html, web

i have created a form on my website that lets others contact me. I used a PHP script to send the email but i always get the error:

This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

I used this code:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" enctype="text/plain">
   Name*:<br>
   <input type="text" name="name" placeholder='Steve'><br>
   E-mail*:<br>
   <input type="text" name="mail" placeholder='john@example.com'><br>
   Comment*:<br>
   <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="400" cols="25" rows="6">
      This site is awesome!
   </textarea>
   <br> <br> 
   <input type="submit" value="Send">
   <input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

**In html and this**:

```
<?php
   if($_POST["message"]) {
       mail("myemail@example.com", "MCPEmaps Comment", $_POST["message"], "From: an@email.address");
   }
?>
```

In the PHP file.

Any help?

Comment: Can you show the error message

Comment: Are u trying it in server or local host

Comment: you did't pass message from your form

Comment: Is the second code snippet the entire content of `contact.php`?

Comment: @justbaron Yes.

Comment: Hmm. Have you tried the contact.php/mail function on it's own? E.g. Add a $_POST['message'] variable/value to the top of the script and then run it? If it still doesn't work, then you can elliminate the form as the cause of the problem.....And where does the error appear? In the contact.php script or the received email?

Answer (score 1):

You are POSTing `comments`, not `message`.

Change this:

```
 <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="400" cols="25" rows="6">
 This site is awesome!
 </textarea>
```

to this:

```
<textarea  name="message" maxlength="400" cols="25" rows="6">
This site is awesome!
</textarea>
```

Comment: Still gives me the error: This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.

Answer (score 0):

Change your html with this, As you are using `$_POST["message"]` but you are not passing it in your html.. So change your this line

`<input type="submit" name="message" value="Send">`

complete code below:

```
<form method="post" action="contact.php" enctype="text/plain">
Name*:<br>
<input type="text" name="name" placeholder='Steve'><br>
E-mail*:<br>
<input type="text" name="mail" placeholder='john@example.com'><br>
Comment*:<br>
  <textarea  name="comments" maxlength="400" cols="25" rows="6">
This site is awesome!
    </textarea>
  <br> <br> 
<input type="submit" name="message" value="Send">
<input type="reset" value="Reset">
</form>
```

Comment: They'd also have to change `$_POST['message']` to `$_POST['comments']` in the PHP `mail` method then.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP will not send the mail because there is no input : message

You can use :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["message"])) {
    mail("myemail@example.com", "MCPEmaps Comment", $_POST["message"], "From: an@email.address");
}
?>
```

And

```
<input type="submit" name="message" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code in your contact.php file:

```
<?php
if($_POST["comments"]) {
    mail("myemail@example.com", "MCPEmaps Comment", $_POST["message"], "From: an@email.address");
}
?>
```

If in case you are using in localhost you need to work lot in your php.ini file. otherwise you get result.